# responsive sidebar scroll up and down

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4, sidebar

I need help with my css code. I don't want my web site to scroll up and down, I want to make it full screen and responsive. I tried css `height:100vh`, `height: 100%` and `height:1920px` but it was still scrolling up and down. This problem is treated in a lot of place, but I could not find a solution that fit my need.

[image]
[image]

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family:sans-serif ;

}
body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#sidebar{
    margin: 90px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background:#22356C ;
    left: -240px;
    transition: all 500ms linear;
}
#sidebar.active{
    left:0px;
}
#sidebar ul li {
   color:white;
   list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 10px;

}
#sidebar .toggle-btn{
    position: absolute;
    left: 310px;
    top: 5px;
}
#sidebar .toggle-btn span{
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 5px;
    background:#22356C ;
    margin: 5px 0px ;
}
#menu{
    position: absolute;
     margin: 40px 220px;
    height: 128px;
    width: 100%;

}
#menu1{
position: absolute;
    margin:0px 100px;
    color:white;
    list-style: block;
}
#bolock{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#page{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 90px 50px;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li>
                Admin  <img src="icones/admin.png" height="35" width="35" align="right">
            </li>
            <li>Frigo&nbsp;<img src="icones/frigo.png"height="35" width="35"align="right"></li>
            <li><img src="icones/arow%20(1).png" height="10" width="10" onclick="myFunction()">&nbsp; Paramétrage<img src="icones/Composant%209%20–%201.png"height="35" width="35"align="right"> <ul id="Paramétrage">
                <div id="menu1"style="display:none;">
                    <li><a href="index.html" target="bolock">Alerts</a></li>
                    <li>Produit</li>
                    <li>contrainte espace</li>
                    <li>compte</li>
                </div>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <img src="icones/logo%20bws.png" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        </a>
        <div id="menu">
            <img src="icones/balise.png"onclick="togglesidebar()">
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="logs">
            <p>
                <img src="icones/Groupe%20102.png"height="40" width="40">&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </p><p>
            <img src="icones/Groupe%20104.png"height="40" width="40">
        </p>
        </div>
    </nav>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="page">
        <iframe name="bolock" frameborder="0" id="bolock"></iframe>
    </div>
<script>
    function togglesidebar() {
        document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle('active');
    }
</script>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("menu1");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    }
    }
    </script>
<script src="css/popper.min.js.js" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="css/slim.min.js.js" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="css/bootstrap.min.js.js" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

### responsive sidebar

Comment: First, you can try to remove the html errors with this : https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add the property

```
overflow: hidden
```

to the body tag

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your question is that you want that there must be no scrolling at all in the web page, then add `overflow: hidden;`to the body and the your page will never scroll at all until there is no internal link in it. ([learn more about overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp))

Now, the next thing, if you want the body to scroll but don't wants the sidebar to scroll along with it as if it is fixed. Then, try the `position: fixed;` property of CSS to the element which needs to be fixed at its place and should not be scrolling ([learn more about positions](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)).